# Conditions in Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

If I have a parser than reads a string of numbers separated by spaces into a list of Ints, how do I handle a trailing space? At the moment I have:

```
row :: Parser [Int]
row  = do
  optional spaces
  f <- (many (oneOf "0123456789"))
  r <- ((char ' ') >> row) <|> pure []
  pure (read f:r)
```

Which works fine with a string that does not have a trailing space but fails with a trailing space.

```
>λ= parse row "" " 2  0 12  3     7"
Right [2,0,12,3,7]

>λ= parse row "" " 2  0 12  3     7  "
Right [2,0,12,3,7,*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

What is the solution to this problem and more so, how would I have a condition where if `'\n'` is consumed then the parser returns `[]`

EDIT:
From reading @amalloy's answer and the parsec source code, I thought it useful to add a version that works here (although, @amalloy's advice to not try and roll existing functions makes more sense)

```
row :: Parser [Int]
row = do
  spaces
  f <- (read <$> many1 digit)
  do
    many1 $ char ' '
    r <- row
    pure (f:r) <|> pure [x]
  <|> pure []
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of implementing all this low-level stuff yourself, I suggest just using [`sepEndBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.15.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:sepEndBy). For example,

```
row :: Parser [Int]
row = spaces *> (int `sepEndBy` many1 space)
  where int = read <$> many1 digit
```